# installing a specific update and change timezone for all domain users through active directory

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain-controller, timezone

In my country Jordan the government decided to cancel the daylight saving time, so the timezone was (UTC +2) and now it is (UTC +3), however microsoft released a hotfix update for this issue. 
now I need to install this update (KB2779562) on all my domain PCs (except the servers) and insure that the timezone is set to (Amman UTC +3) (because some PCs are set to another country's timezone).

is there a way to do this through active directory (because I have over 200 PCs!)?

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you use WSUS to manage Windows Updates in your domain? You can easily add [hotfixes to WSUS with the Microsoft Update Catalog site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708583(v=ws.10).aspx).  Else, what methods are you currently using to deploy software? Group Policy? Startup/Logon scripts? 3rd part agents?

Comment: yes sure we have WSUS thanks for the link, and we use group policy and Startup/Logon scripts for for deploying softwares but no third party. so how can I change the timezone for all PCs?
thanks for the response

Answer (score 3):

To deploy KB2779562 on your computers, you can use WSUS or any other methods (in WSUS you can set the deadline for the update to some time in the past to force the update to be applied immediately).

Changing the time zone is done differently depending on the OS version:

- On Windows 7 or Server 2008 R2 you can use `tzutil /S "<New Time Zone>"`. This utility is [documented](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875624%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), and [should also be present in Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825053.aspx).
- On Windows Vista and Server 2008 (not R2) you can install the [KB2556308](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2556308/en) hotfix which adds the `tzutil` program, then use the same solution as for Windows 7/2008 R2. This hotfix most likely cannot be deployed using WSUS, so you will need to install it using a script.
- On Windows XP or Server 2003 you can use `tzchange /C "<New Time Zone>"`. This utility does not seem to be documented officially, and is not present in newer OS versions.

Comment: thanks Sergey for the info, you mean that I can write these commands as a script right? if so how could I implement the script on different OSs (I have windows 7 and XP) is there an if statement or something like that?